# how to simplify a toggle function with many divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

on my Website I have a page with FAQs. There are many questions, that I want to hide until someone clicks on the question, then the answer should appear. I already have a solution, I just have the feeling this solution is way to complicated. I just don't find a solution how to make it easier. Do you have any suggestions? See the code below, I hope it is self-explaining - if not just let me know ;-)

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
                    answer = document.getElementById("answer" + i);
                    $(answer).hide();
                }
                question1 = document.getElementById("question1");
                question2 = document.getElementById("question2");
                question3 = document.getElementById("question3");
                question4 = document.getElementById("question4");
                question5 = document.getElementById("question5");

                answer1 = document.getElementById("answer1");
                answer2 = document.getElementById("answer2");
                answer3 = document.getElementById("answer3");
                answer4 = document.getElementById("answer4");
                answer5 = document.getElementById("answer5");

                $(question1).click(function() {
                    $(answer1).toggle();
                });
                $(question2).click(function() {
                    $(answer2).toggle();
                });
                $(question3).click(function() {
                    $(answer3).toggle();
                });
                $(question4).click(function() {
                    $(answer4).toggle();
                });
                $(question5).click(function() {
                    $(answer5).toggle();
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: can you share the html as well

Comment: If you are not stuck with a specific problem, then perhaps this question is better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could, for example, rewrite like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    $( '#answer' + i).hide();

    (function( index ) {
      $( '#question' + index ).click( function(){
         $( '#answer' + index ).toggle();
      });
    })( i );
  }
});
```

1. you are already using jQuery, so skip the `document.getElementById()` and use the jQuery selector here.
2. You are repeating the same code over and over again. Move it to the loop.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this code:

```
$(function() {  
   $('h3[id^="question"]').on('click', function() {
      $(this).next('div').toggle();
   });    
});
```

As a sidenote, you could initially hide the answers simply using css if you use html5 boilerplate, e.g.

```
div[id^="answer"] {
   display: none;
}

.no-js div[id^="answer"] {
   display: block;
}
```

where `.no-js` is the class defined for the `html` element and removed with a script (e.g. *modernizr*)

Comment: I'd have use classes instead of `id^=` but this is so far, the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a job for regular expressions!

You can target all of the questions using a regular expression CSS selector, then grab the index from the id and use it to target the appropriate answer.

```
$('[id^="answer"]').hide();

$('[id^="question"]').click(function() {
  var index = this.id.replace('question', '');
  $('#answer' + index).toggle();
});
```

Tested this code with the following example http://jsfiddle.net/B6CBq/1/

Answer (score 1):

use of structured html and css classes will make this really simple

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.answer').hide();
    $('.question').click(function(){ 
    var holder = $(this).closest('.qaholder');
        $('.answer',holder).toggle();
    });
});
```

check out the structure at http://jsfiddle.net/yCYFT/

Answer (score 0):

Write a common function which accepts ID of the question. Call this method inside onclick. 
Put the question in span/div and inside the function get the element inside function and call toggle.

Answer (score 0):

Give the html as below

```
<h3><a href="#" onclick="faq_toggle('faq_150');">What is the purpose of site?</a>
<p id="faq_150" style="display: none;">The site to tell about wordpress</p>
```

Javascript function is below

```
function faq_toggle(id) {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
    e.style.display = ((e.style.display!='none') ? 'none' : 'block');
}
```

Or

```
function faq_toggle(id) {
        $('#'+id).toggle();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    (function(answer) {
        $("#question" + i).click(function() {
            answer.toggle();
        });
    })($("#answer" + i).hide());
}
```

Comment: I have tried that before, but then only the last answer appears, no matter which question I have clicked

Comment: @BrigitteFellner this is due to the value of `i` when the click event occurs. In order to preventing this, the code inside the cycle could be wrapped in a self executed function

Comment: @BrigitteFellner this code should work because `i` is not inside a callback.

Comment: @jcubic But `answer` is.

Comment: @Sirko Yea you right, just check `for (var i=0; i<10; ++i) { var foo = "hello" + i; setTimeout(function() { console.log(foo); }, i*10); }` I thought that with object it will be different then if I use just `i`.